# Labeling matplotlib.pyplot.scatter with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, visualization, scatter-plot

I have a pandas dataframe which I want to apply as labels to each point on a scatter plot. With respect to data, it is clustering data and the dataframe contains labels to each point and in which cluster it belongs. Would be helpful to project that on scatter plot above. I tried using annotate and came up with error.
Below is my code for scatter plot:

```
 import hdbscan
 import numpy as np
 import seaborn as sns
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd
 import umap 
 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
 import sklearn.cluster as cluster
 from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score, 
 adjusted_mutual_info_score

 se1= umap.UMAP(n_neighbors = 20,random_state=42).fit_transform(data_1)

 cluster_1 = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size = 15, min_samples =3).fit_predict(se1)
 clustered = (cluster_1 >=0)
 plt.scatter(se1[~clustered,0],se1[~clustered,1],c=(0.5,0.5,0.5), s=5, alpha =0.5)
 plt.scatter(se1[clustered,0], se1[clustered,1], c=cluster_1[clustered],s=5, cmap='prism');
 plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I add df1 (960 rows x 1 column) as label to all points in above scatter plot?

```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(cluster_1)
  plt.annotate(cluster_3,se3[clustered,0], se3[clustered,1])
```

*Error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\trivedd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2388, in annotate
    return gca().annotate(s, xy, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trivedd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 791, in annotate
    a = mtext.Annotation(s, xy, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trivedd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 307, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trivedd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 2166, in **init**
    x, y = xytext
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"*

Comment: Please explain more precisely what you need. 960 labels don't seem to make sense. Also, it could help to add more information about your data and the exact libraries you're using.

Comment: Please add triple backticks ``` around your error message so it gets displayed nicer.   The error seems to indicate that one of your parameters is in the wrong format. You probably need a loop to add the annotations one by one.  But the result will be a horrible mess of overlapping text.

Comment: Probably it makes sense to use a package such as bokeh which can create an interactive webpage where you can get the annotations when hovering over the points. See e.g. http://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.3.2/docs/gallery/color_scatter.html  the basic things work quite similar to matplotlib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10),'y':np.random.rand(10),'label':list(string.ascii_lowercase[:10])})
```

a df looks like this

```
x   y   label
0.854133    0.020296    a
0.320214    0.857453    b
0.470433    0.103763    c
0.698247    0.869477    d
0.366012    0.127051    e
0.769241    0.767591    f
0.219338    0.351735    g
0.882301    0.311616    h
0.083092    0.159695    i
0.403883    0.460098    j
```

Try:

```
ax = df.plot(x='x',y='y',kind='scatter',figsize=(10,10))
df[['x','y','label']].apply(lambda x: ax.text(*x),axis=1)
```

gets you this:

[image]

Or if you want to use legend:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import string
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(50), 'y':np.random.rand(50),'label': [int(x) for x in '12345'*10]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='x',y='y',hue = 'label',data = df,legend='full',
                     palette = {1:'red',2:'orange',3:'yellow',4:'green',5:'blue'})
ax.legend(loc='lower left')
```

[image]